# Continous Integration, Azure cloud service, Selenium Tests, repos on github

Tags: azure, selenium, github, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am a beginner web programmer, and my company asked me to research a CI that best suits them. At first they wanted to use VS Team Services because it is free for less than 5 people. The following is our situation

- we have the website hosted as Azure cloud service
- the code for the website is on GitHub and like to keep it that way (dev & master branches)
- there is a separate repository for selenium tests on GitHub (only master branch)

The workflow we like to follow is the following

on GitHub merge with dev branch -> triggers build on Team Services -> build passes -> deploy to testing slot on Azure -> get latest selenium test from Github master branch  -> build and run selenium tests against the testing slot URL on Azure -> test passes -> ask permission to be deployed to production and other slots (like demo).

If any of the builds or test fails, CI stops and sends email to developers.

What I know so far:

I have searched around and managed to trigger auto build on Team Services on a merge with branch. But as I said the main web code and selenium tests are in two different repos and my boss wants to keep them that way.
I also learned that it is impossible to run selenium firefox tests on hosted Team Services build agent so we are planning on using some local PC to build and test ( although we initially wanted everything to happen on Team Services)

Problem #1: is that the test and the main app are in two different repos, so I don't know if Team Services supports chaining builds ( main app build pass -> selenium build and run -> ...  ).
Problem #2 : after the selenium tests pass how do I make VS Team Services deploy to Azure cloud services when the code is on github

if you think this is too complicated to do in Team Services please suggest other work flow that fits Team Services (but keeping repos on github) or other CI service that will do what we want but easier to work with.

Thank you in advance for folks trying to answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also learned that it is impossible to run selenium firefox tests on hosted Team Services build agent so we are planning on using some local PC to build and test

In my experience I've used successfully [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). It's designed to work with *.Net*. Our infra was entirely Azure based, we've used dedicated Selenium Server VM (with configured [Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/) on it), since the TeamCity agents was too weak to carry out a parallel UI tests. The basic idea is that your TC agents run the tests (in my case NUnit) but the browser were created/executed at the Selenium VM.

> But as I said the main web code and selenium tests are in two different repos and my boss wants to keep them that way.

It doesn't matter what Version control you use (even mixed mode), TC supports it. But for the record - I've used Git as well. What you need - is to chain the build steps according to your workflow.

Comment: Thank you @ekostadinov, Teamcity is exactly what I was looking for, it is very customizable and easy to chain builds. The following blog helped with the Azure powershell script. http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/ci-deployment-of-azure-web-roles-using-teamcity